# Sending data to apple Watch in swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

In my app, I am sending data (i.e 'UILabels' and 'UIImage') to apple watch. It is being successfully sent. Now in my watch main view where the data is being displayed which are sent from ios app, I have a button which opens up a table view in which i have taken 1 imageview and 4 labels. Now i want the same data to be displayed in table view also i.e every time i sent data from ios app to watch app, each entry should be displayed which i have sent from ios app and should also be saved.
I want the data to be displayed as same which are being saved in my ios app like this below image
[image: ios app image]:

[image: watch app simulator layout]

source code for IOS app

```
class TicketDetailViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
    let dic1  = NSMutableDictionary()
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    var databasePath = NSString()
    var holding_Ticket_category: String = ""
    var holding_Image: UIImage?
    var hold_ticketName: String = ""
    var hold_ticketDate: String = ""
    var hold_ticketTime: String = ""
    var session: WCSession!
    var imageData: NSData!

    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_grey: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cropped_frame: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var display_image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_type_name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_category: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            self.session  = WCSession.defaultSession()
            self.session.delegate = self
            self.session.activateSession()
        }

        defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        display_image.image = self.holding_Image
        ticket_type_name.text = hold_ticketName
        ticket_date.text = hold_ticketDate
        ticket_time.text = hold_ticketTime
        ticket_category.text = holding_Ticket_category

        let filemgr =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
        var ticketDB: FMDatabase

        databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("ticket_Pass.sqlite")

        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String)
        {     
            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {  
                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {
                 print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }else{
            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {
                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }
    }

    func saveImageToFolder()
    { 
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(holding_Image!)!
        let imageName = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()).png"
        let imagePath = (self.getDocumentsDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        print("imagePath:- \(imagePath)")
        print("image size: \(holding_Image?.size)")

        imageData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imagePath, forKey: "ImagePath")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageData, forKey: "ImageData")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageName, forKey: "ImageName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()   
    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String{
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0]
        print("document path:- \(documentsPath)")
        return documentsPath 
    }

    @IBAction func addTickets(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
                //self.saveImageToFolder()
                let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

                let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                if !result
                {    
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                } else
                {
                    let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved to Database!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                    alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

                    }))

                    self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print(databasePath)
               }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func deleteTickets(sender: UIButton) {
        let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Delete Ticket Details!", description: "Are you sure?", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))
        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func sendToWatch(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
            self.saveImageToFolder()
            let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

            let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if !result
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

            } else
            {

                let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action:
                { (ACTION) -> Void in


                        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath as String)
                        if ticketDB.open()
                        {

//                            let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
                             let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET "

                            let result: FMResultSet? = ticketDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                            if let result = result
                            {

                                let ticketDataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                                while result.next()
                                {

                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imagePath"), forKey: "imagePath")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imageName"), forKey: "imageName")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_category"), forKey: "ticket_category")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_type"), forKey: "ticket_type")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("date"), forKey: "date")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("time"), forKey: "time")

                                    ticketDataArray.addObject(self.dic1)

                                }
                                print("ticketDataArray :  \(self.dic1)")
                            }else
                            {
                                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                            }

                          ticketDB.close()

                        }
                      self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                        if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable
                        {
                            let dict = ["Watchdat":self.dic1]

                            self.session.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: { (replayDic: [String:AnyObject]) in
                                print("success!")
                                }, errorHandler: { (error:NSError) in
                                    print("error")
                            })
                        }
                }))

                self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(databasePath)
            }
        }
```

source code for my watch

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
{
    //print(message.values)

    MessageData = NSMutableDictionary(object: message, forKey: "data")
    print("\(MessageData)")
    watch_ticket_category.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_category"] as! String)")
    watch_displayImage.setImage(UIImage(named: MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["imagePath"] as! String))
    watch_ticketType.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_type"] as! String)")
    watch_ticketTime.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["time"] as! String)")
    watch_ticketDate.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["date"] as! String)")    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you need to use  `updateApplicationContext(_:)`, and store transferred data on iPhone, and share always through `updateApplicationContext` which always it's will have the data updated.